# How to execute command that calls WSL bash in Rust?

Tags: windows, bash, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've created a minimal testing project like this:

```
.
├─scripts
|    └─test.sh
└─src
   └─main.rs
```

The `test.sh`:

```bash
echo "hello"
```

The `main.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

    let mut dir = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    dir.push("scripts");

    let program = format!(
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe /mnt/{}/test.sh",
        dir.display()
            .to_string()
            .to_lowercase()
            .replace(':', "")
            .replace('\\', "/")
    );
    println!("{program}"); // line 15

    Command::new(program)
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .and_then(|p| p.wait_with_output())
        .unwrap();
}
```

My question is: when executing the `main`, it failed with:

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." }', src\main.rs:21:10

However, if I ran the "program" printed in line 15 directly in PowerShell, it just worked, successfully execute the "test.sh" script.

Comment: Argument to Command::new is the executable, without arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add arguments to an executable you must use [Command::arg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg). Now rust tries to execute program `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe /mnt/{}/test.sh`, which of course does not exist.

Try the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

    let mut dir = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    dir.push("scripts");

    let program = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
    let arg = format!(
        "/mnt/{}/test.sh",
        dir.display()
            .to_string()
            .to_lowercase()
            .replace(':', "")
            .replace('\\', "/")
    );
    println!("{program}"); // line 15

    Command::new(program)
        .arg(&arg)
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .and_then(|p| p.wait_with_output())
        .unwrap();
}
```